# i have a lumia530 how can i get my texts and pictures back?

Tags: lumia

I have a Lumia 530 windows phone, the screen has cracked and wont respond. I have tried moving the sim and sd card to another phone already, to no effect. I would really like to get my phots and text messages back. Is there anything like itunes that would do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your photos saved. You have option to automatic upload it to your OneDrive account when you take a picture. If you have all pictures on OneDrive, you can do factory reset, it should resolve your problem. If you don't have it on OneDrive plug your phone with USB cable and get all picture to computer. Then you can upload pictures to OneDrive by computer and do factory reset of your phone. The best solution is to first try with SOFT Reset.

Comment: thats great for the photos thanks, in my panic i hadn't thought about using USB, any idea about the contacts and texts?

Comment: @roo Contacts will be saved on your MS account that you have signed in on your phone.